# How to fix text not appearing on the bottom of the screen

Tags: linux, graphics-card, centos

On CentOS6, NVidia card.

When maximizing a window, strange graphical errors happen to the bottom third of the screen. For example, when maximizing a terminal and typing such that text takes up the entire window, the bottom 1/3 of the text of the window turn blank. This occurs to many programs, including Firefox. Once you highlight the text that should be there, it appears without error.

What makes this stranger is that it only doesn't display text in the bottom-- images, pictures, and other things display fine, but not text. I have tried changing the font of terminal and the issue did not go away.

The issue showed up after a recent power outage (although the computer did not lose power as it was connected to a UPS-- I am unsure if the monitors are also connected to the UPS), so I am inclined to believe that the two are related (occam's razor and all).

**EDIT:** The issue appears to be a software issue, it does not appear when using a liveCD and the memtest and hard drive test passed with flying colors.

Comment: Have you tried booting another OS or a live CD? That should tell you if is a hardware problem or not.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow

Comment: I have booted into a Live CD, done a hard drive error check, and done a memtest. LiveCD worked fine and the tests were all clear.

Comment: Have you tested certain resolutions and refresh rates?  It could be that the LiveCD is using some different resolution or refresh rate that the monitor handles better.